# How GetMulti and PutMulti maintains the order between keys and destination

Tags: go

Here are the signatures of both methods

`func (c *Client) GetMulti(ctx context.Context, keys []*Key, dst interface{}) (err error)` [1]

`func (c *Client) PutMulti(ctx context.Context, keys []*Key, src interface{}) (ret []*Key, err error)` [2]

Both methods take in a slice of `keys` and a slice of destination. The thing which is confusing me here that in go, a slice never guarantees order[3]. So how can the underlying implementation of `GetMulti` and `PutMulti` can rely on the order of keys and use it's index to manipulate the destination struct?

1. https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Client.GetMulti
2. https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#Client.PutMulti
3. [slice iteration order in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346641/slice-iteration-order-in-go)

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. Slice guarantees the iteration order of its elements.

Comment: A slice guarantees order.  The key for dst[i] is keys[i].  This appears to be related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59901038/how-to-retrieve-key-object-from-datastore-returned-object).  Please consolidate the questions if they are indeed about the same issue.

Comment: is it somewhere in documentation?

Comment: @EmAe A slice provides indexed view on an underlying array.  See [slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types),  [index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions), [for range](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range), ... in the specification.